# ubuntu pc connected to tv via onboard hdmi suffers off sync delay when using samsung soundshare

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, audio-sync

I am still not sure where the problem comes from, so I am asking here and I also sent an email to Samsung asking for support.

If anyone can provide me with some pointer on where the problem could arise, I would appreciate a lot.

**The Problem**

When connecting a pc via HDMI to the tv and the tv is connected via soundhsare to the sound bar, the audio grows slowly to be out of sync. The sound is late, not in advanced.

By slowly, I mean it is good at the beginning and the off sync delay just grows over time. At one point, the sound is late of about 1 second. It takes about 5 minutes for it to be cmpletely off sync that much.

When the audio is off sync and I press pause, the audio continues to play for about 1 second. The opposite is true, pressing play again means a silent image for about 1 second.

This problem occurs with firefox flash movies and inside Kodi video player.

**My Setup**

TV
model UN50HU7000
latest firmware

soundbar
model HW-H430
latest firmware

pc

motherboard Asus A78M-A, latest firmware

processor AMD Kaveri A8-7600

HDMI from the motherboard

os: Ubuntu 14.04

**What I tried:**

Sounds works well when sound is coming out of the tv speakers.

Sounds works well when sound bar is connected via analog wires to the tv.

Sounds works well with Windows 8.1 installed on the same machine (It was my previous os).

Sound works well when streaming a movie from my NAS to the tv with the smart tv features.

No effect: changing the default sampling rate from 44.1 KHtz to 48 KHtz on the connected device.

No effect: Trying all the hdmi ports on the tv.

When audio is out of sync, turning restarting the soundbar reset the off sync and audio is correctly sync. The same problem will occur, the off sync will grow.

In a nut shell, the soundhsare has a problem only when the playing device is the one connected via hdmi.
I have no other hdmi device at home to test if it is the hdmi connection.

I have upload my ALSA configuration here: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=a52d403c96edbc59d4b01e58df34a233a9661280

Do you know what the problem is?
Do you have a fix?
If not, I would like to have an idea if the problem is samsung's soundhsare or ubuntu audio encoding sent to the hdmi port. One does not exclude the other...

Thank you,

Jean-Francois